# How to iterate hashmap in JSP using strut tag

Tags: jsp, struts, hashmap

I can print value of a key of HashMap as below

```
<%
HashMap<String,String> students = new HashMap<String,String>();
                students.put("1","Amit");
                students.put("2","Amit");
                students.put("3","Anil");
                students.put("4","Amit");
session.setAttribute( "students", students );
%>
<bean:write name="students" property="1" />
<bean:write name="students" property="3" />
```

How can i print key and its value iteratively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well!! I dint get this answer anywhere after googling. But somehow, hitting the ground, I done it without using EL or scriptlets.

```
<logic:iterate name="students" id="nameObj" scope="session">
        <bean:write name="nameObj" property="key"/>
        <bean:write name="nameObj" property="value"/>
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me (struts2):

```
<s:iterator value="students" var="studentElement">
    <s:property value="#studentElement.key"/>
    <s:property value="#studentElement.value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

there's no need to use bean:write.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using **logic:iterate**

```
<logic:iterate id="id" name="name">

</logic:iterate>
```

refer http://www.techfaq360.com/tutorial/logiciterate.jsp

or you can also use

```
 <s:property value="%{name}" />
```

refer http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2controltags/property-tag.shtml

also go through http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/iterator.html

Comment: Those are two different versions of Struts. The syntax for the `<s:property>` tag is a little suspicious; shouldn't it be *either* bracket notation, *or* dot notation, but not both?